# How do I read a txt file in javascript

Tags: javascript, file

I'm looking for some simple code to read a txt file using JavaScript.  First choice would be record by record, but if it is in an array that is fine too

Comment: JS has no file i/o capabilities. Unless something else embeds the text in js or puts it into an html document (or similar) from which JS can get at the text, you're S.O.L.

Comment: Where does this javascript file exist? What have you tried? What didn't work? Where are you having difficulties?

Comment: @Fred - what platform is this running on?  A browser, Node.js, Rhino, WScript, JScript ... something else?

Comment: @Fred: Where is this txt file coming from?

Comment: It can be done in HTA, but that makes your code a application for windows. Otherwise it is a security issue.

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript standard library does not include any general I/O operations, so reading a file must be delegated to some other library provided by your environment.

For example, if you are targeting a web platform you could make the text file available from the web server and fetch it via an XMLHttpRequest.  Parsing the file would be up to you entirely using things like String slicing and regular expressions.

If you are targeting a "server" platform using node.js or Rhino then you can use the I/O facilities provided with those environments, e.g. the [node.js FileSystem interface](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.5/api/fs.html) and `readFile(filename)` (or [Java's FileReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)), respectively.  Other JavaScript/ECMAScript platforms will likely provide their own utilities for accessing the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean on the local computer, that's not possible if you're talking about web scripting, which I would assume you are (if you're talking about using the WSH or something then you create a FileSystemObject, but that's probably not what you want). If you mean read a file from the server, you would use Ajax:

```
function readText(url) {
    var rq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    rq.open('GET', url, false);
    rq.send(null);

    if (rq.status >= 200 && rq.status < 400) {
        return rq.responseText;
    }

    throw new Error("Couldn't read the requested file; status = " + rq.status.toString());
}
```

And call `readText` with the URL of the file to read.

Comment: You forgot to add if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { rq = new XMLHttpRequest(); }else if(window.ActiveXObject) {... Btw great  function was looking for something like this

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript DOES provide an interface for reading files. It's the `FileReader` API. You can setup an `<input type="file">` for the user to select a file from their machine, then use `.readAsText()`. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 1):

This would be a security concern and highly doubt JavaScript has access to the users hard-drive.